# Error found: Error: Cannot find module 'node_helper'

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, magic-mirror

### I installed the google assistant on the magic mirror, installed MMM-Hotword and MMM-Assistant2 and even npm rebuild, but when I run npm start it showed cannot find node_helper.

Starting MagicMirror: v2.9.0
Loading config ...
Loading module helpers ...
No helper found for module: alert.

#### WARNING! Could not load config file. Starting with default configuration. Error found: Error: Cannot find module 'node_helper'

Loading module helpers ...
No helper found for module: alert.
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'node_helper'
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/home/pi/MagicMirror/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object. (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/default/updatenotification/node_helper.js:6:18)
    at Object. (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/default/updatenotification/node_helper.js:100:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
Whoops! There was an uncaught exception...
{ Error: Cannot find module 'node_helper'
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/home/pi/MagicMirror/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object. (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/default/updatenotification/node_helper.js:6:18)
    at Object. (/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/default/updatenotification/node_helper.js:100:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

and it is my config file
var config = {
    address: "localhost", // Address to listen on, can be:
                          // - "localhost", "127.0.0.1", "::1" to listen on loopback interface
                          // - another specific IPv4/6 to listen on a specific interface
                          // - "", "0.0.0.0", "::" to listen on any interface
                          // Default, when address config is left out, is "localhost"
    port: 8080,
    ipWhitelist: ["127.0.0.1", "::ffff:127.0.0.1", "::1"], // Set [] to allow all IP addresses
                                                           // or add a specific IPv4 of 192.168.1.5 :
                                                           // ["127.0.0.1", "::ffff:127.0.0.1", "::1", "::ffff:192.168.1.5"],
                                                           // or IPv4 range of 192.168.3.0 --> 192.168.3.15 use CIDR format :
                                                           // ["127.0.0.1", "::ffff:127.0.0.1", "::1", "::ffff:192.168.3.0/28"],

```
language: "en",
timeFormat: 24,
units: "metric",

modules: [
    {
        module: "alert",
    },
    {
        module: "updatenotification",
        position: "top_bar"
    },
    {
        module: "clock",
        position: "top_left"
    },
    {
        module: "calendar",
        header: "US Holidays",
        position: "top_left",
        config: {
            calendars: [
                {
                    symbol: "calendar-check",
                    url: "webcal://www.calendarlabs.com/ical-calendar/ics/76/US_Holidays.ics"                   }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        module: "compliments",
        position: "lower_third"
    },
    {
        module: "currentweather",
        position: "top_right",
        config: {
            location: "Daegu,KR",
            locationID: "1835329",  //ID from http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz; unzip the gz file and find your city
            appid: ""
        }
    },
    {
        module: "weatherforecast",
        position: "top_right",
        header: "Weather Forecast",
        config: {
            location: "Daegu,KR",
            locationID: "1835329",  //ID from http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz; unzip the gz file and find your city
            appid: ""
        }
    },
    {
        module: "newsfeed",
        position: "bottom_bar",
        config: {
            feeds: [
                {
                    title: "New York Times",
                    url: "http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml"
                }
            ],
            showSourceTitle: true,
            showPublishDate: true,
            broadcastNewsFeeds: true,
            broadcastNewsUpdates: true
        }
    },
    {
        module: "MMM-Hotword",
        position: "top_right",
        config: {
            chimeOnFinish: null,
            mic: {
                recordProgram: "arecord",
                device: "plughw:1"
            },
            models: [
                {
                    hotwords    : "smart_mirror",
                    file        : "smart_mirror.umdl",
                    sensitivity : "0.5",
                },
            ],
            commands: {
                "smart_mirror": {
                    notificationExec: {
                        notification: "ASSISTANT_ACTIVATE",
                        payload: (detected, afterRecord) => {
                            return {profile:"default"}
                        }
                    },
                    restart:false,
                    afterRecordLimit:0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        module: "MMM-AssistantMk2",
        position: "top_right",
        config: {
            deviceLocation: {
                coordinates: {
                    latitude: 35.857304, // -90.0 - +90.0
                    longitude: 128.4833455, // -180.0 - +180.0
                },
            },
            record: {
                recordProgram : "arecord",  
                device        : "plughw:1",
            },
            notifications: {
                ASSISTANT_ACTIVATED: "HOTWORD_PAUSE",
                ASSISTANT_DEACTIVATED: "HOTWORD_RESUME",
            },
            useWelcomeMessage: "brief today",
            profiles: {
                "default" : {
                    lang: "ko-KR"
                }
            },
        }
    },
]
```

};

Answer (score 0):

See if you have a the file MagicMirror/node_modules/node_helper/index.js
If not, make the file and copy/paste [this code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/master/modules/node_modules/node_helper/index.js).

Just ran into a black screen issue myself and this resolved it for me.